# Python and Appium

Tags: ubuntu, python-appium

I got the following error while executing a python script on appium

**ImportError: No module named appium**

I am running appium in one terminal and tried executing the test on another terminal. Does anyone know what is the reason for this error? and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use nosetest.

Install:
pip install nose

Run:
nosetests (name of the file containing test)